# Catching error that is thrown within the catch of a promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to catch an error that may be thrown within the catch of another promise. (sorry if that is confusing...)

```js
async function throwingError () {
  throw new Error('this error needs to be caught'); // I don't know if I need to return, throw or something else. This function may or may not have an error
};

async function mainFunction () {
  promiseFunction()
    .catch(error => {
      throwingError();
      // I've tried throw throwingError() and return Promise.reject(throwingError());
    });
};

mainFunction().catch(error => `caught: ${console.error}`);
```

Right now, it doesn't catch the error.
From what I know, this doesn't work because the promises finish at different times, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mainFunction` needs to return a Promise. What you're missing is the `return` statement. You also need to return `throwingError()` in the catch block.

Without the `return` statement, the value returned by your `mainFunction` is a Promise that always resolves to `undefined`

```js
async function mainFunction () {
  return promiseFunction()
    .catch(error => {
      return throwingError();
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return promise.

```js
function throwingError () {
  throw new Error('this error needs to be caught');
}
function mainFunction () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reject(throwingError())
  })
};

mainFunction().catch(error => console.log(`caught: ${error}`));
```